# React Native FlatList is not showing data from API (axios)

Tags: api, react-native, axios

I am fairly new to fetching data from an API with React Native, I am using Axios. I'm attempting to fetch categories from an API and list them in a FlatList however it isn't loading on the screen. Here is my code

HomeScreen:

```
import React from 'react';
import { 
    View,
    Text,
    FlatList,
    StyleSheet 
    } from 'react-native';
import ApiData from '../src/api/apiData';

const HomeScreen = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList 
                vertical
                data={ApiData.get('/categories')}/>
            </View>
            );
};
```

apiData

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default axios.create({
    baseURL:"https://developers.api.com/api/v2.1",
    headers: {
        'user-key': 'MyKeyGoesHere'
    }
})
```

this is all I've done so far and am a bit lost. Thank you

Comment: Please provide api response sample and you also forgot renderItem in flatlist.

Comment: @Nagesh sorry, what is api response sample?

Comment: Means which data you want to render in flatlist

Comment: I am rendering the categories section in flatlist

Comment: Yes. I am asking about response of https://developers.api.com/api/v2.1 this api

Comment: @Nagesh I am still a bit confused regarding what you are asking. The API is just a list of data I am trying to retrieve from the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204782/discussion-between-nagesh-and-frank-gully).

Comment: @Nagesh ok I have entered the chat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated my code here please check

https://snack.expo.io/SJZC7tJkL